# Is it possible to select a particular X Scale in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend

For example, if I want to create a x-Axis, I follow two steps before appending the line to the svg.

I create the timescale:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain(d3.extent(props.data, function(d){return d.date}))
                .range([0, chartWidth ]);
```

Then comes the design:

```
const xAxisDesign = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                .tickSize(0, 0)
                .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d.%m %H:%M"));
```

And finally I append the graph:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .style("font-size", "7px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+ chartHeight +")")
  .call(xAxisDesign);
```

If I want to get the Axis from another JS File I use:

```
d3.selectAll('svg').select('.chartAxis')
```

But what I want to do, is to choose the timescale (first step) and change its domain from the other JS File. Is it possible? If it is possible how can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by getting the domain data from another JS file? do you have multiple axis and want to grab the domain from another axis in another chart?

Comment: Exactly, I have two x-axis. The graph looks like this https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f 
Each component is placed in a different JS file (upper-chart.js & brush-zoom.js)
From brush-zoom.js I want to change the domain of x-Axis from the upper chart

Comment: I was thinking that there is maybe a way to reference the xScale and select it from another file, similar to `d3.selectAll('svg').select('.chartAxis')` but I can't find anything. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: yes, you can name both chart axis, with different classnames, after call `.call(xAxisDesign).attr('class', 'bottom-chart')` but not sure if you can recover the domain set you your xAxisDesign  function